# Linq subtraction sum(values) from two tables

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two db.Table1 and db.Table2 with columns named IdUser,Value
I think I should have some join but i miss the logic

it's just a logic it's not a code
how can do something like :

```
var total = Sum(db.Table1(Sum(Value))-db.Table2(Sum(Value))
.Where(db.Table1.IdUser=db.Table2.IdUser)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables and group

```
    var total = from table1record in Table1
        join table2record in Table2 on table1Record.IdUser equals table2Record.IdUser
        group new { table1record,table2record } by table1record.IdUser into groupedRecords
        select groupedRecords.Sum(x=>x.Table1Value) -   groupedRecords.Sum(x=>x.Table2Value);
```