# LiNQ join two tables for substraction SUM

Tags: linq

scenario : View should have sum of all profit , sum of all cost , and balance = profit - cost

```
public ProfitAndCostViewModel getTotalBalance()
    {
        var totalProfit = db.Profits.Where(p=>p.IdUser.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).Sum(p=>p.Value);

        var totalCost = db.Costs.Where(c=>c.IdUser.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).Sum(c=>c.Value);

        var balance = totalProfit - totalCost ;
        return new ProfitAndCostViewModel { FinalBalance = balance };
    }
```

controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {


      var pcv = new ProfitAndCostViewModel();
          pcv.ProfModel =getProfitSum();
            pcv.CostModel =getCostSum();
            pcv.TOTALBALANCE = getTotalBalance();
             return View(pcv);


        }
```

View:

```
@model WHFM.ViewModels.ProfitAndCostViewModel
@Model.FinalBalance.FinalBalance
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430097/linq-subtraction-sumvalues-from-two-tables/15430355#15430355

Check this.

Comment: yeah I see that but now data is not correct.In View it's  show me values with not correct sum. I should have only one sum - FinalBalance why I have two with incorrect data. Have you some Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

scenario : View should have sum of all profit , sum of all cost , and balance = profit - cost

```
public double getProfitSum()
{
    return db.Profits.Where(p=>p.IdUser.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).Sum(p=>p.Value);
}        

public double getCostSum()
{
    return db.Costs.Where(c=>c.IdUser.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).Sum(c=>c.Value);
}
```

controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {


      var pcv = new ProfitAndCostViewModel();
      pcv.ProfModel = getProfitSum();  //This should be a double
      pcv.CostModel =getCostSum();   //This should be a double
      return View(pcv);       
 }
```

Model:

```
public class ProfitAndCostViewModel
{
    public double ProfModel {get;set;}
    public double CostModel {get;set;}
    public FinalBalance {get{ return ProfModel - CostModel;} }
}
```

View:

```
@model WHFM.ViewModels.ProfitAndCostViewModel
@Model.FinalBalance - This show now be correct
```

Comment: what about if I dont have any values in database and open the view : The cast to value type 'Double' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public ProfitAndCostViewModel getTotalBalance()
{
    var totalProfit = db.Profits.Where(p=>p.IdUser.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).Sum(p=>p.Value);

    var totalCost = db.Costs.Where(c=>c.IdUser.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).Sum(c=>c.Value);

    var balance = totalProfit - totalCost ;
    return new ProfitAndCostViewModel{ FinalBalance = balance};
}
```

From what I can see, you are only looking for the final balance of the current user, right? If so, you don't need to return an IEnumerable of ProfitAndCostViewModel.

If you want to have a many to many user-balance output (an IEnumerable of ProfitAndCostViewModel) then try:

```
 public IEnumerable<ProfitAndCostViewModel> getTotalBalance()
 {
    var result = from p in db.Profits
                       group p by p.IdUser.UserId
                       into g
                       join c in db.Costs on g.Key equals c.IdUser.UserId
                       group new {g,c} by g.Key into h
                       select new ProfitAndCostViewModel
                           {
                               FinalBalance = h.Select(x=>x.g.Sum(y=>y.Value)).First() - h.Sum(x=>x.c.Value),
                                                       UserId = h.Key
                           };

    return result;
}
```

I only tested this on lists, not DB variables so it may not work.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your previous comment. Can you reword it? Comments ignore new lines as well...

Comment: I will reEdit the question

Comment: what I want is "From what I can see, you are only looking for the final balance of the current user, right? If so, you don't need to return an IEnumerable of ProfitAndCostViewModel." you said it correct

Comment: i change my code and now worked with you first answer.This very clean solution 10x a lot i accept Answer +1

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<ProfitAndCostViewModel> getTotalBalance()
{
    var total = from p in db.Profits
                join c in db.Costs on p.IdUser.UserId equals c.IdUser.UserId
                group new { p, c } by p.IdUser.UserId into g
                select new ProfitAndCostViewModel
                {
                    FinalBalance = g.Sum(i => i.p.Value) - g.Sum(i => i.c.Value);
                };
    return total;        
}
```

Comment: I reEdit my post get only data from current User but I don't give a correct data.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 public IEnumerable<ProfitAndCostViewModel> getTotalBalance()
 {
     var total = from p in db.Profits
                 join c in db.Costs on p.IdUser.UserId equals c.IdUser.UserId
                 where p.IdUser.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId
                 group new { p, c } by p.IdUser.UserId into g
                 select new ProfitAndCostViewModel
                 {
                    FinalBalance = g.Sum(i => i.p.Value) - g.Sum(i => i.c.Value)
                 };
     return total;       
  }
```

Comment: omg I miss where clause 10x :) . But 511 -9.95 it's not 481.15

Comment: Yea, this isn't going to work. If you have multiple profits and costs with the same userid you'll have a lot of rows being joined resulting in the costs and/or profits being summed multiple times. In your case, I'm guessing you had 3 profit entries and 1 cost entry resulting in the cost being join on 3 times and being subtracted from the profit 3 times (511 -9.95 -9.95 -9.95 = 481.15)

Comment: The link seems to be a user who has many profits and many costs. What is his total balance of all profits minus all costs.